# how can i get $(document).height() NEW value when new data has been added?

Tags: jquery

Lets suppose that **$(document).height()** is 1000. Then i insert a new div at the bottom of the page with height=100. The **$(document).height()** should be 1100 but it keeps throwing 1000 to me.

How can i get the new $(document).height() dynamically?

Thank!

Comment: Show the code where you're using it - it does not have this problem by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(document).height() works fine for me in this case.

If you're using a variable to hold the $(document).height(), make sure you update it when the action is performed to insert the new div at the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<span class="click">test</span>
```

JS:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
var height = $(document).height();
console.log(height);
for(var i=0; i< 10; i++){
$(".click").append("<div>test</div>");}
});
```